# how to select in database all selected in multiple select in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Here is my process

```html
  $sec_id = implode(', ', $_POST['sec_id']);

  $stmtSec = $crud->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_section WHERE sec_id IN (':sec_id')");
  $stmtSec->execute(array(":sec_id" => $sec_id));
  while ($rowSec = $stmtSec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
     $section[] = $rowSec['section'];
  }
```

But nothing shows using my codes.

Here's my multiple select code.

```html
                      <select name="sec_id[]" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker form-control border-input" style="text-align-last:center;" title="Select Section" required multiple>
                        <?php
                        $stmtSection = $crud->runQuery('SELECT * FROM tbl_section ORDER BY sec_id DESC');
                        $stmtSection->execute();
                        while($rowSection=$stmtSection->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                          print("<option value='".$rowSection['sec_id']."'>".$rowSection['section']."</option>");
                        }
                        ?>
</select>
```

Is there another way of selecting multiple in database? or query? 
Please help.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: also: `implode(', ', $rowSec['section'])` implies that `tbl_section .section` is an array which is a very strange thing to have in a relational database

Comment: can you please give an example

Answer (score 0):

Here I have included and updated the code.

```
    $sec_id = implode(', ', $_POST['sec_id']);
    $stmtSec = $crud->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_section WHERE sec_id IN (':sec_id')");
    $stmtSec->execute(array(":sec_id" => $sec_id));
    while ($rowSec = $stmtSec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $section[] = $rowSec['sec_id'];
    }
    $stmtSection = $crud->runQuery('SELECT * FROM tbl_section ORDER BY sec_id DESC');
    $stmtSection->execute();
    while($rowSection=$stmtSection->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $optionsSelected = in_array($rowSection['sec_id'], $section) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        print("<option'" . $optionsSelected . "'value='".$rowSection['sec_id']."'>".$rowSection['section']."</option>");
    }
```

Comment: please take a look from my query again. I update the question.